# Send HTML form input in an email as a PDF attachment using PHP

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, fpdf

I would like to create a form that takes basic input from a user. I would like to send this data in the form of a PDF document to another user through an email.

- The user gives some input values in the form
- Once the user submits the form, the data should be converted to PDF and should be emailed to the administrator

I wanted to find out if there is a way to accomplish this without storing the file on the server.

Comment: I did not mean to ask people to do it for me. I just wanted to make sure if there is a way to send the pdf without storing it on the server. Anyways, I edited the question and I also was able to accomplish it. I'm posting it so that it could be useful for other guys. You can use PHPMailer to do this. The code looks somewhat like this: $mail = new PHPMailer();
...
$doc = $pdf->Output('', 'S');
$mail->AddStringAttachment($doc, 'doc.pdf', 'base64', 'application/pdf');
$mail->Send();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:
You can use PHPMailer to do this. 
The code looks somewhat like this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
...
$doc = $pdf->Output('', 'S'); 
$mail->AddStringAttachment($doc, 'doc.pdf', 'base64', 'application/pdf'); 
$mail->Send();
```